# Get Value from Different (Non-Referenced) assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I have two Projects (under same solution) - `Teacher` and `Student`.
`Student` project has reference of `Teacher`.

```
public static class Student
{
public static readonly string SchoolName="ABC University";
}
```

Now how can I access `SchoolName` from `Teacher` project.

Is it really possible? If yes, can you please tell me the way.

I am noob in programming. So, pardon me if this is a very silly question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should merge the two projects. Is there any reason you have two different projects for such interdependent things as a student and a teacher?

Comment: @CédricBignon I am facing the problem in some already designed code. This is just an example.

Comment: Unless your codebase is big or there is a very good reason to do this, my advice is to merge the two projecs.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a third project. This project is referenced by the two other. In the third project you can save, e.g. global values in an easy way. (such as your static values). But sure, you have to set the values in the third project by your Student project.

To access real "object" properties, you will have to make a little bit more work, like defining general Interfaces in the third project.

But I can think you can go with the first approach.

Maybe not the best way, but a way that works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can access the assemblies which you have not referenced to your project. Following is the code you can use.

In the following method, i have a user control in the assembly and i am accessing that without referencing it. You can change the code as per your need. This code is in VB, you need to change it to c#. :-)

```
        Dim oAssembly As Assembly = Nothing
        Dim oType As Type = Nothing
        Dim oUserControl As System.Windows.Forms.UserControl = Nothing

Dim oArgs As [Object]() = New [Object]() {Me} 'Arguments that you need to pass to the assembly

        Try
            ' Set Assembly 
            oAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Your DLL Path")

            For Each currentType In oAssembly.GetTypes()
                If currentType.Name.ToLower.Contains("Name of the class or object in assembly") Then
                    oType = currentType
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            oUserControl = DirectCast(oAssembly.CreateInstance(oType.FullName, True, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, Nothing, oArgs, Nothing, Nothing), System.Windows.Forms.UserControl)

            Return oUserControl
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
```

Comment: I think this solution will not help in his usecase, since the Type and the property he is looking for is defined in not referenced assembly. In your example the "UserControl" is a general type defined in a third assembly. Therefore you can access it. Indeed,  it is possible also to look for properties by strings, but this is more a hack then a solution.

Comment: This is an academic solution; it's not practical here.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some steps:

1. Add Reference of Student Project to Teacher Project
2. You can access the static class Student, by coding from **Teacher Project** like this:

   ```
   void DoSomething() {
       string schoolName = Student.SchoolName;
   }
   ```

Comment: He already has a reference to `Teacher` project in `Student` project. With step 1, you just create a circular reference dependency.

Comment: Yes @CédricBignon, he got it right, I express the usage thru code.  Thanks.

Comment: @PeytonCrow That will be not a solution here. I can't remove the Teacher reference from Student project for some dependency.

Comment: @sigma67, it is the solution stated in your problem and that is actually the straight one there.  It is either you use another pattern in your projects, like using contracts above it to hide the poor design of the projects.  You can then re-post the design of the project then edit your post.  Then we can see the design and where you can put the contracts to achieve what you want.